# Virto Commerce compile errors after updating nuget packages in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: virtocommerce

After downloading Virto Commerce source and compiling in Visual Studio all went smoothly. After updating NUGET Packages, I get compile errors. Please see graphic.

[Compile errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neRk6.png)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have updated `Netonsoft.Json` and it cause obsolete method compilation error.

You should avoid updating nuget packages yourself, this should be done by the platform team.

Answer (score 0):

I've applied only Minor Updates and all works as expected.

So, I recommend to install major updates of NUGET packages carefuller.